# jqGrid treeGrid, client side Pagination is not working

Tags: jqgrid, pagination, treegrid

I'm trying to apply the pagination in the jq treeGrid. I have written the custom code for pagination, once the "treeGrid":true, then the level 1 items, i.e. child's are not displayed and when "treeGrid":false, then the pagination is working but the child element in the tree is also displayed as a level 0 items.

Can someone please help me out.`

```
"rowNum":2,
    "rowList":[2,5,10,20],
"loadComplete": function() {
                    var i, myPageRefresh = function(e) {
                        var newPage = $(e.target).text();
                        $("#tree").trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:newPage}]);
                        e.preventDefault();
                    };

                    $($("#tree")[0].p.pager + '_center td.myPager').remove();
                    var pagerPrevTD = $('<td>', { class: "myPager"}), prevPagesIncluded = 0,
                        pagerNextTD = $('<td>', { class: "myPager"}), nextPagesIncluded = 0,
                        totalStyle = $("#tree")[0].p.pginput === false,
                        startIndex = totalStyle? this.p.page-2*2: this.p.page-2;
                    for (i=startIndex; i<=this.p.lastpage && (totalStyle? (prevPagesIncluded+nextPagesIncluded<2*2):(nextPagesIncluded<2)); i++) {
                        if (i<=0 || i === this.p.page) { continue; }

                        var link = $('<a>', { href:'#', click:myPageRefresh });
                        link.text(String(i));
                        if (i<this.p.page || totalStyle) {
                            if (prevPagesIncluded>0) { pagerPrevTD.append('<span>,&nbsp;</span>'); }
                            pagerPrevTD.append(link);
                            prevPagesIncluded++;
                        } else {
                            if (nextPagesIncluded>0 || (totalStyle && prevPagesIncluded>0)) { pagerNextTD.append('<span>,&nbsp;</span>'); }
                            pagerNextTD.append(link);
                            nextPagesIncluded++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (prevPagesIncluded > 0) {
                        $($("#tree")[0].p.pager + '_center td[id^="prev"]').after(pagerPrevTD);
                    }
                    if (nextPagesIncluded > 0) {
                        $($("#tree")[0].p.pager + '_center td[id^="next"]').before(pagerNextTD);
                    }
                }
    `
```

Answer (score 0):

TreeGrid don't support pagination. It's native restriction on the implementation. All collapsed items will be hold on the page hidden. Moreover displaying of TreeGrid with many levels is really problematic in TreeGrid.

You can imagine the following structure

```
t0
  t11
    t2
      t4
        node1
  t12
    t2
      t4
        node2
```

What should be displayed in case of the page size 5 (`rowNum: 5`) or even in case of `rowNum: 2` like you use? Something like

```
        node1
        node2
```

or

```
      t4
        node1
      t4
        node2
```

Even `rowNum: 5` could show something like

```
    t2
      t4
        node1
    t2
      t4
        node2
```

where one don't see that the the `node1` and `node2` have different parents on the level 1.

It should be clear that one should always display the full path till the root  element:

```
t0
  t11
    t2
      t4
        node1
```

but one have to have `rowNum` larger as the the number of levels of tree items.

The problem will be much more difficult if you would try to display collapsed items first, but then the user clicks on expanding the node and it should generate changing the page to stay inside of the page size defined by `rowNum`.

I tried to explain you that implementation of paginating in TreeGrid is probably really not possible. It it would be possible, then only with a lot of restrictions and one could immediately provide examples where the implementation displays really terrible results.

Comment: what you are telling is correct Oleg but if we do pagination for the level 0 items then there will be no limitation. And we can get the desired results. If you understand what I mean to explain you, is there any solution ??
so,
t0
  t1
    t2
      t3
        t4
  t0
   t1
    t2
      t3

Comment: @RahulPrakash: I tried to explain you that 1) **no pagination** could be good too; 2) if you would suggest one implementation way then I could suggest you immediately and example of the tree data where your solution will be look not good. If you and me would choose one implementation which would be good enough for us then it will come the 3-d person which will have another opinion.